# Android - Is there a way to skip the "lock screen" for HTC One?

Tags: android

I am creating an application that sometimes launches a screen using the [StandoutWindow](https://github.com/pingpongboss/StandOut) component

It works like a charm on most of the devices i have tested out, but on the HTC One, when the lock screen is activated, i can't see the window, it is actually placed behind that lock screen.

Anyone has any advice on how to position my window on top of everything?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this one:

```
KeyguardManager keyguardManager =(KeyguardManager)getSystemService(Activity.KEYGUARD_SERVICE);
KeyguardLock lock = keyguardManager.newKeyguardLock(KEYGUARD_SERVICE);
lock.disableKeyguard();
```

and add this to your android manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.DISABLE_KEYGUARD"/>
```

Comment: Where exactly should i put that? I have tried but maybe i'm trying it in the wrong place

Comment: Seems like this method is deprecated.